# sql server how to decollapse data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to decollapse data with in same group.

let me explain by example.

Demo data:

```
 +-------------+----+------------+-----------+
|  Primarykey | ID | START_Point| STOP_Point|
+-------------+----+------------+-----------+
|           1 |  1 |          1 |        10 |
|           2 |  1 |          2 |         4 |
|           3 |  1 |          5 |         5 |
|           4 |  1 |          5 |         5 |
|           5 |  1 |          5 |        15 |
|           6 |  2 |          5 |         5 |
|           7 |  2 |          2 |         2 |
|           8 |  2 |          1 |        10 |
|           9 |  2 |          1 |        20 |
+-------------+----+------------+-----------+
```

Data should be decollapse with in group:

Expected output:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| primarykey | SubjectID | START_Point| STOP_Point|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         1 |          1 |         1 |
|          1 |         1 |          2 |         4 |
|          1 |         1 |          5 |         5 |
|          1 |         1 |          6 |        10 |
|          2 |         1 |          2 |         4 |
|          3 |         1 |          5 |         5 |
|          4 |         1 |          5 |         5 |
|          5 |         1 |          5 |         5 |
|          5 |         1 |          6 |        10 |
|          5 |         1 |         11 |        15 |
|          6 |         2 |          5 |         5 |
|          7 |         2 |          2 |         2 |
|          8 |         2 |          1 |         1 |
|          8 |         2 |          2 |         2 |
|          8 |         2 |          3 |         4 |
|          8 |         2 |          5 |         5 |
|          8 |         2 |          6 |        10 |
|          9 |         2 |          1 |         1 |
|          9 |         2 |          2 |         2 |
|          9 |         2 |          3 |         4 |
|          9 |         2 |          5 |         5 |
|          9 |         2 |          6 |        10 |
|          9 |         2 |         11 |        20 |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Logic :
There should not be any Start_Point - Stop_Point range  which overlap within same group.

Explanation:

Group By on "ID"

For Primary key =1,

We have start_point = 1 and Stop_point =10

Now if we check other rows for ID = 1 (Because group by ID) then we can see 
Primarykey 2,3,4 and 5 which data is overlap within range 1-10

so we want to decollapse 1-10 to 1-1,2-4,5-5,6-10.

same logic should be apply for each row.

I do not want to use cursor or row by row fetching and processing logic  as my query will be applied on bulk data and that will slow down processing.

Please let me know if I am failed to explain anything or anything looks confusing to you.

Its bit challenging but I know there are many experts we have on stack overflow.

Looking for some solid solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so we want to decollapse 1-10 to 1-1,2-4,5-5,6-10.how is this done?

Comment: `primarykey = 5` shows `start_point` and `stop_point` as 5-15. how does it become `6-10`? and how will it work for `id = 2`?

Comment: We can help you find a solution. But first you need to provide the details of your question. You are trying to expand your data somehow but we don't understand what the business rules are. From what you posted it doesn't make any sense to me. And "decollapse" is not a word, I think you mean expand.

Comment: Is there a unique key somewhere for each row?

Comment: @user2315555, 5-15 should be expand to 5-5,6-10 and 11-15 because there is already one range 5-5 and 1-10 so we need to split 5-15 to 5-5(we have one row 5-5),6-10(we have onerow row 1-10) and 11-15

Comment: @Sean Lange , may be Expand is correct word and thanks to mark it. Business scenario: In clinical trial data , when we want to find adverse event effect on certain date range across all volunteer with in same study, this expanded data will be used to show adverse event chart. so Start_point and Stop_Point is actually date field but to make it easy here I have show number field.

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, yes how it is done with in same group and here group by is ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point you can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Idx, StartStop, 
       LEAD(Idx) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IdxRowNum) AS NextIdx,
       LEAD(StartStop) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IdxRowNum) AS NextStartStop
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Idx, StartStop, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Idx, StartStop) AS IdxRowNum                         
    FROM
      (SELECT ID, START_Point, STOP_Point
       FROM @T) Src
    UNPIVOT (
      Idx FOR StartStop IN (START_Point, STOP_Point)
    ) AS Unpvt
) t
```

to make a table of start - end points for each time span of every ID contained in your original table.

Using the above query as a basis you can get all existing intervals for each ID:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, StartIdx, StopIdx
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, 
           CASE 
             WHEN StartStop = 'START_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'START_Point' THEN 
                CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN Idx ELSE NULL END
             WHEN StartStop = 'STOP_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'STOP_Point' THEN 
                CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN Idx + 1 ELSE NULL END
             WHEN StartStop = 'STOP_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'START_Point' THEN 
                CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN Idx + 1 ELSE NULL END
             WHEN StartStop = 'START_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'STOP_Point' THEN Idx           
           END AS StartIdx, 
           CASE 
             WHEN StartStop = 'START_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'START_Point' THEN 
                CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN NextIdx - 1 ELSE NULL END
             WHEN StartStop = 'STOP_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'STOP_Point' THEN 
                CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN NextIdx ELSE NULL END
             WHEN StartStop = 'START_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'STOP_Point' THEN NextIdx
             WHEN StartStop = 'STOP_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'START_Point' THEN 
                CASE WHEN NextIdx = Idx + 1 THEN NextIdx WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN NextIdx- 1 ELSE NULL END
             ELSE Idx
           END AS StopIdx
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, Idx, StartStop, 
               LEAD(Idx) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IdxRowNum) AS NextIdx,
               LEAD(StartStop) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IdxRowNum) AS NextStartStop
        FROM (
            SELECT ID, Idx, StartStop, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Idx, StartStop) AS IdxRowNum                         
            FROM
              (SELECT ID, START_Point, STOP_Point
               FROM @T) Src
            UNPIVOT (
              Idx FOR StartStop IN (START_Point, STOP_Point)
            ) AS Unpvt
        ) t
    ) s
) u
WHERE StartIdx IS NOT NULL AND StopIdx IS NOT NULL
```

The output from the above query is:

```
ID  StartIdx StopIdx
-----------------------
1   1        1
1   2        4
1   5        5
1   6        10
1   11       15
2   1        1
2   2        2
2   3        4
2   5        5
2   6        10
2   11       20
```

Using the previous query in a CTE and performing a `CROSS APPLY` finally gets you what you want:

```
; WITH IntervalsByID AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, StartIdx, StopIdx
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN StartStop = 'START_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'START_Point' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN Idx ELSE NULL END
                 WHEN StartStop = 'STOP_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'STOP_Point' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN Idx + 1 ELSE NULL END
                 WHEN StartStop = 'STOP_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'START_Point' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN Idx + 1 ELSE NULL END
                 WHEN StartStop = 'START_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'STOP_Point' THEN Idx           
               END AS StartIdx, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN StartStop = 'START_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'START_Point' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN NextIdx - 1 ELSE NULL END
                 WHEN StartStop = 'STOP_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'STOP_Point' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN NextIdx ELSE NULL END
                 WHEN StartStop = 'START_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'STOP_Point' THEN NextIdx
                 WHEN StartStop = 'STOP_Point' AND NextStartStop = 'START_Point' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN NextIdx = Idx + 1 THEN NextIdx WHEN NextIdx > Idx THEN NextIdx- 1 ELSE NULL END
                 ELSE Idx
               END AS StopIdx
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ID, Idx, StartStop, 
                   LEAD(Idx) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IdxRowNum) AS NextIdx,
                   LEAD(StartStop) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IdxRowNum) AS NextStartStop
            FROM (
                SELECT ID, Idx, StartStop, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Idx, StartStop) AS IdxRowNum                         
                FROM
                  (SELECT ID, START_Point, STOP_Point
                   FROM @T) Src
                UNPIVOT (
                  Idx FOR StartStop IN (START_Point, STOP_Point)
                ) AS Unpvt
            ) t
        ) s
    ) u
    WHERE StartIdx IS NOT NULL AND StopIdx IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT t.PrimaryKey, t.ID, s.StartIdx, s.StopIdx
FROM @T AS t
CROSS APPLY 
( 
   SELECT * 
   FROM IntervalsByID
   WHERE ID = t.ID AND t.START_Point <= StartIdx AND t.STOP_Point >= StopIdx
) s   
ORDER BY PrimaryKey, StartIdx
```

Output:

```
    PrimaryKey  ID  StartIdx    StopIdx
   --------------------------------------
    1           1   1           1
    1           1   2           4
    1           1   5           5
    1           1   6           10
    2           1   2           4
    3           1   5           5
    4           1   5           5
    5           1   5           5
    5           1   6           10
    5           1   11          15
    6           2   5           5
    7           2   2           2
    8           2   1           1
    8           2   2           2
    8           2   3           4
    8           2   5           5
    8           2   6           10
    9           2   1           1
    9           2   2           2
    9           2   3           4
    9           2   5           5
    9           2   6           10
    9           2   11          20
```

Comment: Sir Hats off... Your solutions works like charm..Thanks a lot.. You are really star.. This question looks simple but its solution is same complex..You apply great logic...Please let me know if I can follow you on any site or blog.. Again Thanks a lot...