# SQL query to split records by intervals

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, intervals

Let's assume I have a table which has columns `From` and `To` which are dates and a bit type column which identifies whether it is a cancel (1 = cancel). Also an `Id` which is a PK and `CancelId` which references what is cancelled.

Let's say I have records which look like:

```
Id From       To         IsCancel CancelId
1  2015-01-01 2015-01-31 0        NULL
2  2015-01-03 2015-01-09 1        1
3  2015-01-27 2015-01-31 1        1
```

I am expecting the **result** to show what intervals of then non-cancel records are still uncancelled:

```
Id From       To
1  2015-01-01 2015-01-02
1  2015-01-10 2015-01-26
```

I can make it so it would split each record into dates, then subtract cancelled dates from the records then merge the intervals but since I have quite a lot of records, I find this very inefficient and am pretty sure that I am overlooking something simple.

Comment: This is totally incomprehensible to me. I don't understand the relation with input and output data. Try to rephrase.

Comment: Let's say you have a holiday for a whole month of 2015-Jan. However, you are asked to go to work on days 03-09 and on days 27-31. The real holidays that you had were 01-02 and 10-26. Does that explain better? :)

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Take a look at this article. It explains how to group islands of dates like this quite nicely. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Comment: You may have a loot at this similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996331/sql-server-how-to-decollapse-data/27002428#27002428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you want to achieve is non trivial. A possible solution involves placing all *From* / *To* dates in an *ordered sequence*. The following `UNPIVOT` operation:

```
SELECT ID, EventDate, StartStop, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID, EventDate, StartStop) AS EventRowNum,
            IsCancel                         
FROM
    (SELECT ID, IsCancel, [From], [To]
     FROM Event) Src
UNPIVOT (
     EventDate FOR StartStop IN ([From], [To])
) AS Unpvt
```

produces this result set:

```
    ID  EventDate   StartStop   EventRowNum IsCancel
   --------------------------------------------------
    1   2015-01-01  From        1           0
    2   2015-01-03  From        2           1
    2   2015-01-09  To          3           1
    3   2015-01-27  From        4           1
    3   2015-01-31  To          5           1
    1   2015-01-31  To          6           0
```

Using a `CTE`, you can subsequently simulate `LEAD` function (available from SQL Server 2012 onwards) in order to place in a single record the current and the next date from the sequence above:

```
;WITH StretchEventDates AS 
( 
    -- above query goes here
), CTE AS
(
   SELECT s.ID, s.EventDate, s.StartStop, s.IsCancel,
          sLead.EventDate As LeadEventDate, sLead.StartStop AS LeadStartStop, sLead.IsCancel AS LeadIsCancel
   FROM StretchEventDates AS s
   LEFT JOIN StretchEventDates AS sLead ON s.EventRowNum + 1 = sLead.EventRowNum
)
```

The above produces the following result set:

```
    ID  EventDate   StartStop   IsCancel    LeadEventDate   LeadStartStop   LeadIsCancel
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   2015-01-01  From        0           2015-01-03      From            1
    2   2015-01-03  From        1           2015-01-09      To              1
    2   2015-01-09  To          1           2015-01-27      From            1
    3   2015-01-27  From        1           2015-01-31      To              1
    3   2015-01-31  To          1           2015-01-31      To              0
    1   2015-01-31  To          0           NULL            NULL            NULL
```

Using `CASE` statements you can filter these records in order to get the desired output.

Putting it all together:

```
;WITH StretchEventDates AS 
( 
    SELECT ID, EventDate, StartStop, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventDate, StartStop) AS EventRowNum,
            IsCancel                         
    FROM
        (SELECT ID, IsCancel, [From], [To]
        FROM Event) Src
    UNPIVOT (
        EventDate FOR StartStop IN ([From], [To])
    ) AS Unpvt
), CTE AS
(
   SELECT s.ID, s.EventDate, s.StartStop, s.IsCancel,
          sLead.EventDate As LeadEventDate, sLead.StartStop AS LeadStartStop, sLead.IsCancel AS LeadIsCancel
   FROM StretchEventDates AS s
   LEFT JOIN StretchEventDates AS sLead ON s.EventRowNum + 1 = sLead.EventRowNum
), CTE_FINAL AS
(SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN StartStop = 'From' AND IsCancel = 0 THEN EventDate
            WHEN StartStop = 'To' AND IsCancel = 1 THEN DATEADD(d, 1, EventDate)
       END AS [From],
       CASE WHEN LeadStartStop = 'From' AND LeadIsCancel = 1 THEN DATEADD(d, -1, LeadEventDate)
            WHEN LeadStartStop = 'To' AND LeadIsCancel = 0 THEN LeadEventDate
       END AS [To]
FROM CTE
)
SELECT ID, [From], [To]
FROM CTE_FINAL
WHERE [From] IS NOT NULL AND [To] IS NOT NULL AND [From] <= [To]
```

You may have to add additional `CASEs` in the query above to handle additional combinations of 'cancelations' following 'non-canceled' (and vice-versa) events.

With the data provided in the OP the above yields the following output:

```
ID  From    To
---------------------------
1   2015-01-01  2015-01-02
2   2015-01-10  2015-01-26
```

Comment: I have just ran this against my test data and it failed at one certain case where a person was on holidays until the very end of the period: exact example being: 01-09 and cancels being 01-02 and 05-06. It returned only 03-04, "forgetting" the 07-09 part. Thus I modified your query slightly adding, as you said, another case. Now `[To]` looks like: `CASE WHEN LeadStartStop = 'From' AND LeadIsCancel = 1 THEN DATEADD(d, -1, LeadEventDate)
   WHEN LeadStartStop = 'To' AND LeadIsCancel = 0 THEN LeadEventDate
       END AS [To]`. You did a huge job with this query!

Comment: Oops, it broke another test. I will post once I figure it out. Adding a final condition of  
 `AND [From] <= [To]` seems to have fixed it too. Now it looks like it is amazing :)

Comment: @ Andrius Naruševičius These 'CASEs' are a real pain in the @@@! If you fiddle around with your data you will get it working at the end!

Comment: I know, right! I had a paper and was drawing schemes like crazy! I am going to play with a few more tests and once I get it surely working, I will edit your answer slightly (to fix that small issue I told about) for the further use for community. I cannot thank you enough!!! I learned a lot today :)

Comment: One more major adjustment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventDate, StartStop)` adding `ID` as the major order otherwise it is not working for the condition `s.EventRowNum + 1 = sLead.EventRowNum` when the source table contains more than one Id to work with.

Comment: @Andrius Yes but now the query is not working with the sample data posted in the OP. Can you place a more comprehensive sample data set in the OP and I will have a look at it tomorrow.